# Magento setup resources not working in magento 1.8.1

Tags: install, setup-script, ce-1.8.1.0

Personal I'm trying to create an installation script for magento module, but the problem is that he's not running my script and not save the core_resource table, anyone have any idea why that is?

I followed the following tutorial
[Magento – Install, install upgrade, data and data upgrade scripts](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/)

[image]

Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_DBScript>
            <version>3.1.5.6</version>
        </Inchoo_DBScript>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <inchoo_dbscript>
                <class>Inchoo_DBScript_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>inchoo_dbscript_resource</resourceModel>
            </inchoo_dbscript>
            <inchoo_dbscript_resource>
                <class>Inchoo_DBScript_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <ticket>
                        <table>inchoo_dbscript_ticket</table>
                    </ticket>
                    <comment>
                        <table>inchoo_dbscript_comment</table>
                    </comment>
                </entities>
            </inchoo_dbscript_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <inchoo_dbscript_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Inchoo_DBScript</module>
                </setup>
            </inchoo_dbscript_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

sql\inchoo_dbscript_setup\install-3.1.5.6.php:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('inchoo_dbscript/ticket'))
    ->addColumn('ticket_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
    ), 'Id')
    ->addColumn('title', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Title')
    ->addColumn('description', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Description');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('inchoo_dbscript/comment'))
    ->addColumn('comment_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
    ), 'Id')
    ->addColumn('comment', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Comment');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
$installer->endSetup();
```

app\etc\modules\Inchoo_DBScript.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_DBScript>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Inchoo_DBScript>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: yes I got same problem in my module..please help us

Comment: I'd start by checking the `core_resource` table for your extension.  If there's an entry in there for your `inchoo_dbscript_setup` resource in means Magento already thinks its installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script working fine. May be you have some mistake. Check again following issue.

1. Clear cache
2. Your module need have proper permission(like read+write+execute permission)

Now run!

Enjoy coding :)

Comment: I cleared the cache but did not work on the file permissions would be?

Comment: Can you check your file and folder name spelling.

Comment: names checked and are correct